# Mount ext2 sd card with BusyBox

Tags: android, busybox

I am trying to mount an sd card that I put into my tablet.  The sd card is in ext2 format.  I tried using BusyBox with the following command in my terminal app on the tablet:

```
busybox mkfs.ext2
```

But it seems I need to add some arguments to the command.  What commands would I need to add to it?  Or is there an easier way to mount the sd card?

I would like to not format the sd card as there is data on it; but whatever it takes to read it as ext2 format is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `busybox mount /dev/block/something /mountpoint`. `mkfs` creates a filesystem like `format` in Windows

http://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#mount

> Or is there an easier way to mount the sd card?

It usually happens automatically, check `busybox mount` without arguments if it is already mounted somewhere.

Comment: What values do I use for "something" and "mountpoint"?  How can I figure those out?

Comment: @zapl : but isn't it an action which can be only performed by the Super User?

Comment: @user2284570 Maybe. But you probably had root if you managed to install busybox.

Comment: @zapl : No... Installing busybox [never required root access](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=burrows.apps.busybox).

Answer (score 2):

you need to *mount* the ext2 filesystem not create the filesystem.

Depending on your tablet, the device in /dev could be different from my example.  but in general you want to run a similar command :

```
busybox mount -t ext2 /dev/block/vold/179:2 /data/sd-ext
```

where */dev/block/vold/179:2*  is the device that you are trying to mount.

and */data/sd-ext* is the path where you want to mount your sd card to.

here's the help page for the mount command

```
1|shell@android:/ $ busybox mount -t
option requires an argument -- t
BusyBox v1.20.0.git (2012-03-21 01:44:00 GMT) multi-call binary.

Usage: mount [OPTIONS] [-o OPTS] DEVICE NODE

Mount a filesystem. Filesystem autodetection requires /proc.

    -a      Mount all filesystems in fstab
    -f      Dry run
    -i      Don't run mount helper
    -r      Read-only mount
    -w      Read-write mount (default)
    -t FSTYPE[,...] Filesystem type(s)
    -O OPT      Mount only filesystems with option OPT (-a only)
-o OPT:
    loop        Ignored (loop devices are autodetected)
    [a]sync     Writes are [a]synchronous
    [no]atime   Disable/enable updates to inode access times
    [no]diratime    Disable/enable atime updates to directories
    [no]relatime    Disable/enable atime updates relative to modification time
    [no]dev     (Dis)allow use of special device files
    [no]exec    (Dis)allow use of executable files
    [no]suid    (Dis)allow set-user-id-root programs
    [r]shared   Convert [recursively] to a shared subtree
    [r]slave    Convert [recursively] to a slave subtree
    [r]private  Convert [recursively] to a private subtree
    [un]bindable    Make mount point [un]able to be bind mounted
    [r]bind     Bind a file or directory [recursively] to another location
    move        Relocate an existing mount point
    remount     Remount a mounted filesystem, changing flags
    ro/rw       Same as -r/-w

There are filesystem-specific -o flags.
```

Comment: How do I determine what the device id?

Comment: 1.) unplug sdcard  2.) *ls /dev/block*   3.) plug in sdcard  4.) *ls /dev/block*   5.) compare to see what showed up

Comment: I think dmesg will also yield the info you seek.  Plug in your sdcard,  adb shell in to your device and type *dmesg*